# Can sp.js be used in 2007?

Tags: 2007, javascript

I'm trying to use the code found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185010(v=office.14).aspx under the section 'Adding a Web Part To A Page With Javascript'. However I cannot get a reference to the file SP.js. Is this found in 2007 or is it only 2010 and on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Neither the Client Object Model nor the REST API are available in SharePoint 2007. However, you can use the SOAP (ASMX) web services. If you're going to do so from JavaScript I highly recommend you use Marc Anderson's [SPServices jQuery plug-in](http://spservices.codeplex.com/).

You said you were looking to add a web part to a page. Here are a couple resources that should help you do so using SPServices:

[AddWebPart Documentation](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AddWebPart)

[SPServices Stories #3 – AddWebPart Method of the WebPartPages Web Service](http://sympmarc.com/2013/01/21/sharepoint-stories-3-addwebpart-method-of-the-webpartpages-web-service/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code at the top of the page:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="sp.js" LoadAfterUI="true"
    Localizable="false" runat="server" ID="ScriptLink1" />
```

[Source](http://canoosh.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/sharepoint-2010-client-object-models-%E2%80%93-the-ecmascript-library/)

Comment: That's for 2010 isn't it?

Comment: Ah yes my bad, thought it was for 2007 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

SP.js is a part of [JavaScript Class Library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee538253%28v=office.14%29) in [SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model (CSOM)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee537247%28v=office.14%29)

It is not supported to use in previous versions of SharePoint including  SharePoint 2007

The CSOM acts as a proxy to connect to a [WCF service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.5/ms735119%28v=vs.90%29) (Client.svc) for the processing of the request. The Client.svc service is the [protocol](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-csomspt/8ebba305-5af3-477d-bf4f-ad378a39eaba) server responsible for performing all of the operations requested by the client object model. For more details see, for example [Working with the ECMAScript Client Object Model (JSOM) in SharePoint 2010–Part 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20151002060311/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/07/13/working-with-the-ecmascript-client-object-model-jsom-in-sharepoint-2010-part-1-nikhil-sachdeva.aspx). This kind of functionality is not available in SharePoint 2007.